# What Azure assembly has reference to ServiceBusTriggerAttribute?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-topics

The ["How to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK" Azure Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#trigger) article shows the usage of `[ServiceBusTrigger]` attribute for integrating a WebJob and Azure Service Bus Topic messages. However, using the default Azure WebJobs project template in Visual Studio 2015, the reference to ServiceBusTrigger causes the following compile time exception:

*The type or namespace name 'ServiceBusTriggger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

The problem at hand is the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs package from Nuget doesn't contain the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute class.

Is there a Nuget package that can be added that will include this much needed class?

I have tried including the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package from Nuget, but that doesn't contain it either.

Without the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute I am unable to get this WebJob connected to consume messages from an Azure Service Bus Topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to include the **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus** NuGet package as mentioned in the Prereq section of this article
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#prerequisites

Comment: And if you have trouble installing that, try updating Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions first. :)

Answer (score 7):

This answer is correct for **Functions 1.x**, but if you are using **Functions 2.x**, then you need to install [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus):

Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

Here is the Microsoft documentation [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

***Also, make sure you reference the latest package and update any dependent packages.***

Answer (score 4):

The [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus) package from Nuget contains the `ServiceBusTriggerAttribute` class.

Answer (score 0):

My trouble was that I had a project of type `Azure Functions v2 Preview` which uses .NET standard instead of the .NET Framework.

Creating a new project of the old v1 type and importing `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` via NuGet got me on my way.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Functions v2 Preview (.NET Standard 2.0), you need to install the prerelease version of **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus**:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus -IncludePrerelease
```

Or via NuGet Package Manager:

[image: NuGet Package Manager screen]